# Modificador de acesso para métodos em Java - Default

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Acabei de fazer uma prova e achei uma questão meio suspeita, gostaria da opinião de vocês.

> Na linguagem de programação Java, quando o método de uma   classe
>   não   possui   um   modificador   de   acesso explicitamente declarado
>   significa que esse método pode ser acessado
>
> (A) por todas as classes do mesmo pacote em que foi declarado.
>
> (B) por   qualquer   outra   classe,   além   daquela   a   que
>   pertence.
>
> (C) pela classe a que pertence, de forma exclusiva.
>
> (D) pela classe em que foi declarado e suas subclasses, e por membros
>   de outras classes no mesmo pacote.

Eu penso que a resposta D está correta, inclusive em um teste que fiz o método se comportou normalmente e sem nenhum problema em tempo de compilação e em tempo de execução:

```
class Teste {
    String teste() {
        return "ola";
    }
}

class Teste2 extends Teste {

}

class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Teste2 t = new Teste2();
        System.out.println(t.teste());
    }
}
```

O gabarito preliminar informa que a resposta correta é (A).

Comment: Está certa, é a letra A mesmo. Sem modificador de acesso, qualquer membro de classe é acessível por todas as classes que estejam no mesmo pacote.

Comment: Tente fazer o mesmo teste que você fez, criando 2 arquivos de classes diferentes e sem herança, mas dentro do mesmo pacote.

Comment: Se quiser algo mais concreto e oficial, veja a tabela explicativa na documentação da oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: @diegofm então o erro estão em afirmar que tenho acesso pelas subclasses? Pelo que entendi, eu posso ter acesso nas subclasses mas desde que estas estejam no mesmo pacote ne? Se eu tiver pacotes diferentes não posso usar herença... Acho que caí num peguinha haha Então acho que a opção estaria correta somente se informasse que fosse as subclasses mas pertencentes ao mesmo pacote.

Comment: Exatamente isso, modificador padrão restringe acesso a membros de uma classe A somente a outras classes que compartilhem o mesmo pacote, independente se há herança ou não. Tanto que na tabela até mostra que, mesmo se uma classe B herdar de A mas estiver fora do mesmo pacote, mesmo sendo "filha" ela também não enxergará membros default. -> ``The third column indicates whether subclasses of the class declared outside this package have access to the member.``

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda! Acabei de testar aqui e vi que realmente não dá certo.

Comment: Por que vocês não criam uma resposta para ficar melhor registrado?

Answer (score 1):

Uma resposta só para ficar registrado:

A resposta é a letra A. Se não tiver modificador de acesso especificado, então o acesso é package(pacote).

Se uma **subclasse estiver em outro pacote, não terá acesso/visibilidade** ao método ou propriedade da classe Pai com modificador de acesso igual a pacote.